# How to open a specific scene from another package C# Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Anyone has an idea how can I open a specific scene from one apk to another apk? Like I'm in the apk com.example1.test and want to go to the Scene MainMenu from apk com.example2.test.

Thank you in advance,

Léon

Comment: Android provides `Intent` class for something like that, but you will end up just opening a different application like you would when you share a text from one application to the other. And `Intent` will work only if the second application knows how to handle that `Intent`. It must be explicitly programmed. Just simply opening a screen from a different application is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct easy way to do it in Android.

You can always store the parameters in the cloud (maybe using SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier as a key) open the other app, fetch your parameters.